# PowerBI Online, How to configure R credentials?

Tags: r, powerbi

I created a simple test report.

1. retrieves a list of data from sharepoint
2. using R script to transform the table

This works fine - Power BI Deskop, can refresh and apply the R script.

However, after publishing to Power BI online I cannot refresh the dataset due to the R script's credentials that are not set?

How do I set the credentials to make the Power BI report refresh online?

[image]

when I try and setup the credentials it just hangs?
[image]

Comment: Any luck?  Seems that MS hasn't REALLY integrated R too much in their PBI product!!!

Comment: Also wondering if you've had any luck with this, I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Hi everyone, I had to create a Personal Gateway on our on-premises server, which has the required R and also Python libraries installed. This way your online Power BI report can 'run' R and Python stuff - if you wire the report to your gateway which allows Power BI online report to use your own server with the libraries installed. I guess you could also create a Virtual Server within MS Azure and installed the libraries + install a gateway to allow your Power BI online reports to 'work' I hope this helps.